# labels on chartjs, are unclickable when screen size is smaller

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm having as issue, with chartjs,
When my screen size is smaller, I can't click labels, maybe just one of them but not all of them, like they are disabled or I don't know.

```
function generatePieChart(data, labels, chartElementId) {
    var colors = new Array();

    var randomColorFactor = function () {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    };
    var randomColor = function (opacity) {
        return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        colors.push(randomColor(0.7))
    }
    var config = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: data,
                label: labels,
                backgroundColor: colors,
            }],
            labels: labels
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById(chartElementId).getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```